# Examples of holomorphic, complex differentiable, always positive functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, big-list

I am looking for classes of functions which are:

```
    1) holomorphic 
    2) |f(z)|>0 for all z
    3) complex differentiable (i.e. f(z)=mod(z) is not valid)
```

Particularly I am looking for functions whose complex derivatives are less complicated.

While conditions $(1)$ and $(3)$ may be too general, in particular I am interested in condition $(2)$, namely that for all complex numbers the function value is greater than zero.

For example, $\exp(z)$ would meet the conditions, because $|\exp(z)|$=$1>0$

If this question is too general, please let me know and I will think of further conditions to impose.

Comment: Note that conditions (1) and (3) are equivalent. You are simply looking for holomorphic functions omitting the value $0$. I suspect the answer is just the set of functions of the form $e^f$ with $f$ holomorphic, but I can't prove it

Comment: Holomorphic in which domain? $f(z) = 1/z$ is holomorphic and nonzero in $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$. – And $|\exp(z)|$ is positive in $\Bbb C$, but not everywhere equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All such functions can be written in the form

$$f(z) = \exp(g(z))$$

where $g$ is holomorphic. Such functions certainly satisfy your condition, and the fact that *all* such functions can be written in this form follows from the existence of the logarithm of non-zero functions.

Comment: Your answer confirms what I thought was the case. +1 for you, good answer.

Comment: The domain is not specified in the question, so it should perhaps be added that this is true for $f$ holomorphic in $\Bbb C$ (or any simply-connected domain).

Comment: I can see that $f(z) = \exp(g(z))$ is holomorphic, but I can't *see* that all function in discussion can be written like that. Could you please add a hint for those slow at mind and lazy for look-up (like me, and other casual readers)?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Since $f$ is never zero, $f'/ f$ exists and has a primitive $g$; this $g$ is the logarithm of $f$, and the exponential part follows.